# Order independent variadic template base specialization

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, c++17

On GCC/Clang The following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<typename X, typename T, typename ...Ts>
void v(X& x, T& value, Ts&... args)
{
    v(x, value);
    v(x, args...);
}

template<typename X, typename T>
enable_if_t<is_integral_v<T>>
v(X& x, T& value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

template<typename X, typename T>
enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<T>>
v(X& x, T& value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

int main() {
    float f = 5.5;
    int i = 2;
    v(f, i, i);
}
```

Giving the error:

```
> prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void v(X&, T&, Ts& ...) [with X = float; T = int; Ts = {}]':
> prog.cc:8:3:   required from 'void v(X&, T&, Ts& ...) [with X = float; T = int; Ts = {int}]'
> prog.cc:27:14:   required from here
> prog.cc:9:3: error: no matching function for call to 'v(float&)'
>   v(x, args...);
>   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~
> prog.cc:6:6: note: candidate: template<class X, class T, class ... Ts> void v(X&, T&, Ts& ...)
>  void v(X& x, T& value, Ts&... args)
>       ^
> prog.cc:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> prog.cc:9:3: note:   candidate expects at least 2 arguments, 1 provided
>   v(x, args...);
>   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If the variadic function is defined after all the base function specializations are defined, the code compiles, but then you get this very undesirable constraint that makes code break with you include things in the wrong order.

Is there a way to add specializations to the variadic base function in a way that doesn't depend on definition order?

Comment: They are not specializations, but overloads. And you cannot call functions that has not been seen yet, that's a general rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problems in your code.

First and most impostant: you give the same name (`v()`) to functions that are doing two completely different things; the first `v()` call a printing function over the first argument and call recursively itself for the following arguments. Tho other `v()` are printing (SFINAE selected) functions.

Suggestion: use different names; in the following example I've used `foo()` for the recursive function and `bar()` for the printing function.

Second: your first argument (`X & x`) is unused.

Suggestion: remove it.

Third: your function are receiving not-const references but they don't modify the values.

Suggestion: receive the arguments as const references; so you can call also `v(5.5f, 3L)` (you can't call this way with not-const references)

Following this suggestions, your printing functions become

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>{}> bar (T const & value)
 { std::cout << "integral case: " << value << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>{}> bar (T const & value)
 { std::cout << "floating case: " << value << std::endl; }
```

and the recursive function (adding the ground case)

```
// ground case
void foo ()
 { }

// recursion case
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (T const & value, Ts const & ... args)
 {
    bar(value);
    foo(args...);
 }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>{}> bar (T const & value)
 { std::cout << "integral case: " << value << std::endl; }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>{}> bar (T const & value)
 { std::cout << "floating case: " << value << std::endl; }

// ground case
void foo ()
 { }

// recursion case
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (T const & value, Ts const & ... args)
 {
    bar(value);
    foo(args...);
 }

int main ()
 {
   float f {5.5};
   int i   {2};

   foo(f, i, i, 3L, 6.6f);
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP say

> The main problem is still left unsolved - `bar`s have to be defined before `foo`.

If you accept that `bar`s become static methods in a struct, I propose the following `bar` struct

```
struct bar
 {
   template <typename T>
   static std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>{}> func (T const & value)
    { std::cout << "integral case: " << value << std::endl; }

   template <typename T>
   static std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>{}> func (T const & value)
    { std::cout << "floating case: " << value << std::endl; }
 };
```

and `foo` become

// ground case

```
template <typename>
void foo ()
 { }

// recursion case
template <typename Bar, typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (T const & value, Ts const & ... args)
 {
   Bar::func(value);
   foo<Bar>(args...);
 }
```

and is called as follows

```
foo<bar>(f, i, i, 3L, 6.6f);
```

The following is a full working example where the `bar` struct is defined after `foo()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// ground case
template <typename>
void foo ()
 { }

// recursion case
template <typename Bar, typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (T const & value, Ts const & ... args)
 {
   Bar::func(value);
   foo<Bar>(args...);
 }

struct bar
 {
   template <typename T>
   static std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>{}> func (T const & value)
    { std::cout << "integral case: " << value << std::endl; }

   template <typename T>
   static std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>{}> func (T const & value)
    { std::cout << "floating case: " << value << std::endl; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   float f {5.5};
   int i   {2};

   foo<bar>(f, i, i, 3L, 6.6f);
}
```

Comment: The X type is left there from my actual problematic code to make sure I'm comparing apples to apples, and left unused because it isn't needed to demonstrate the problem.
The main problem is still left unsolved - `bar`s have to be defined before `foo`.

Comment: @Enhex - my last suggestion was wrong; sorry. But I've another solution (see the improved answer) that could solve the definition order problem.

Comment: I've been looking into the Cereal library and it does a similar thing of using classes but for the variadic template instead of the overloads, which makes the overloads easier to extend. I'm trying to apply the class approach to my problem right now.